# 8 queen problem in old TPJ aritcle is missing link to main module Queen

Tags: perl, oop

Does anyone have full program for this below from perl journal?

https://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol1_4/tpj0104-0001.html

More specifically below link comes up nothing.

http://www.tpj.com/programs.html

This is the one w/ 8 queens program. I was reading the program and wanted to study it but this article does not contain complete programs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

require Queen; 
require Queen::Null;

my $lastQueen; 
my $column; 
my $neighbor = new Queen::Null;

foreach $column (1 .. 8) { 
    $lastQueen = new Queen; 
    $lastQueen->initialColumn($column, $neighbor); 
    $neighbor = $lastQueen;
}

$lastQueen->first() and $lastQueen->print();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The author Mike Stok's [web page](http://www.stok.ca/%7Emike/subjective-look/) (the article in [PDF](http://www.stok.ca/%7Emike/subjective-look/tpj-article.pdf))
2. His [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mikestok/perl-8-queens/)